# Are there any code samples for Uno platform accessing MSSQL, PostgreSQL or MYSQL?

Tags: database, uno-platform

I have tried various ways to connect to different DB engines (asynchronously), but they all failed when I deployed the code and executed it via my browser in WASM format. The code worked well for UWP tho, so I'm a bit baffled.

Although there's a sample for SQLLite in browser, it wasn't too helpful for me. Hopefully someone could give me a few pointers to continue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for SQLite is about running the database inside of the browser itself, but not about running it from a remote database.

If you need to have such a support, you will need to have a .NET SQL provider that supports plain HTTP/S or WebSockets, which is available for cloud-based databases.

In general though, you may want to consider a WebAssembly app as a mobile app for which it is best to access remote resources like databases through a Web API.

Note that the Chrome developers have in mind [the creation of a RAW sockets API](https://github.com/WICG/raw-sockets), which would enable TCP non-HTTP connections to be created.